# What is correct way to import the angularjs library when using typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I work on a large application that imports the angularjs library like so:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

However, I just [fixed a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496529/angularjs-testing-with-typescript-why-do-all-my-tests-fail-with-angular-mock-m) in our test runner by changing the import style in the spec files to:

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

What is the difference and which should I use for AngularJS v1.5.7?

Comment: what module loader are you using

Comment: we are using systemjs.

Comment: If angularjs exports a top level angular object you may be assigning the alias to contain it. So the difference would be `angular.angular` for the `* as angular`

Comment: we are getting angularjs from a vendor file, but we do register it with systemjs in the index.html like `System.registerDynamic('angular', [], false,function(require, exports, module){module.exports =  window.angular});`

Comment: edited my comment but the second method of import will be the safest in the long run.

Comment: do you register angular dynamically in your testbed as well?

Comment: yes, we register angular in a custom specRunner.html file the same as i pasted. I guess im just confused by how the typescript compiles okay when I do not see any default export for the `angular` variable in the angularjs library.

Comment: It comes from the @types folder for angular in index.d.ts

Comment: your ts config probably points to a directory with your types and then when it compiles it looks in the index.d.ts for that library. Its wildly convoluted.

Comment: yes - i see that. But the angular typing does not declare angular as a default export, so why dont I have to import it like `import { angular } from 'angular'`? (Thanks for all your help btw.)